# is memory getting leaked?

Tags: c++

i have method which takes normal pointer to string

```
void parseResponseData(char* response);
```

and i am calling this as below

```
parseResponseData((char *) response.c_str());
```

response is std::string type. My assumption is that it may not be the best way for converting const char* to char* and secondly i may be leaking memory in this case? Need expert opinions on that? especially i am looking if am leaking memory on this.

Comment: What makes you think that you would be leaking memory?  What does parseResponseData do?

Comment: you could always use a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to check for leaks yourself..

Comment: const is there for a reason.  Silencing your compiler is not the same as solving your problem.

Comment: conversion from const char* to char* made me think that may be a copy is created and that i may need to free afterwards.  thanks guys will try to avoid removing the const-ness.

Comment: That's why it's recommended to avoid c-style casts.  If you want to convert from one type to another, making a copy, use `static_cast` instead.  Of course, it won't compile, and that will give you the clue that you need to find another solution.

Answer (score 3):

You really should not cast like that. Overall avoid doing c-style cast in c++ and also removing const-ness is almost never a good option. If you have to remove a const from a pointer use `const_cast` and **REALLY** try to avoid that.

The memory will not be leaked as string still takes ownership of it.

Answer (score 2):

Your question does not provide enough information to be answered definitively.

Why does `parseResponseData` require a non-const pointer to its input string? Does it modify the string? If so, then you will not be able to use it with `std::string` directly. `std::string` does not provide any interface that would allow you to modify it as a C-style string. Even if you don't care to preserve those modifications, it is still illegal to modify the buffer returned by `std::string::c_str()`.

If `parseResponseData` does not modify the string, then what you have now should work (assuming `parseResponseData` does not attempt to store the pointer for long-term use). There's no memory leaks here, since the `std::string` object retains the ownership of the buffer returned by `c_str()` and the responsibility to deallocate it. However, it still looks pretty ugly on `parseResponseData` part: if it is a non-modifying operation, it should take a `const char *`.

Comment: Re "if it is a non-modifying operation, it should take a `const char *`" - Better: It should take a `const std::string&`. Using C-style strings instead of C++'s `std::string` is a sign of a C++ newbie (been there, done that). Once you know better, those C++ newbie decisions to use C-style strings will result in years of pain and self embarrassment because you can no longer switch to `std::string` without break your users. You're stuck. Anyhow, +1.

Comment: it is modifying operation - and i think simplest or relatively ok solution would be to change the casting from C style to const_cast.

Comment: @Qooraf: What kind of "modifying operation"? Do you expect the modifications to persist in the original `std::string`? In general case it won't work, since in general case the buffer returned by `c_str()` is a completely independent buffer. If you wan't to settle for an ugly hack of some sort, I'd say that `&response[0]` would be a better idea. This does not work either in general case, but if it happens to work in your implementation, I'd say this ugly hack has more common sense in it than a `c_str()`-based ugly hack.

Answer (score 0):

Once `response` goes out of scope, the underlying C string will be freed. The call to `parseResponseData()` does **not** make a copy of the C string, only a copy of the pointer. So there is no memory leak.